# Using the Well Ordering Principle to prove the first principle of mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Theorem** (The Well Ordering Principle): A least element exists in any non empty set of positive integers.
>
> Use the Well Ordering Principle to prove the first principle of mathematical
>   induction.
>
> **Proof:** Let $S$ be the set of positive integers containing the integer $1$, and the integer
>   $k + 1$ whenever it contains $k$. Assume also that $S$ is not the set of all positive
>   integers. As a result, there are some integers that are not contained in $S$ and thus
>   those integers must have a least element $\alpha$ by the well ordering principle. Notice
>   that $\alpha \neq 1$ since $1 \in S$. But $\alpha − 1 \in S $ and thus using the property of $S$, $\alpha \in S$.
>   Thus $S$ must contain all positive integers.

What I do not understand about this proof is how they managed to come up with the assumption that $S$ is not the set of all positive integers and draw a conclusion from there. It seems like a proof by contradiction to me, since they are trying to contradict the Well Ordering Principle. Could anyone explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ***is*** a proof by contradiction.

- We want to show that $S$ contains all positive integers;
- We temporarily assume the opposite, and find that it leads to a contradiction (namely that there is a positive integer $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\notin S$ and $\alpha\in S$);
- We conclude that $S$ must have contained all positive integers.

Comment: Can it be interpreted as a proof by contrapositive as well ?

Comment: A proof by contraposition of the Principle of Mathematical Induction would involve proving that ***if*** $S$ is a set of positive integers that **does not** contain every positive integer, ***then*** either $1\notin S$ or there is some $k\in S$ such that $k+1\notin S$. That does not describe the proof under discussion, but of course there is some ambiguity as to describing when one proof is "the same as" another proof.

Comment: Am i right to say that ' Any nonempty subset of negative integers has the greatest element. ' is the contrapositive of the original statemnt of the WOP?

Comment: No, that's not correct.

Comment: My version of the proof:We want to show that S contains all positive integers; We first assume that S contains all negative integers, hence the least element $a$ have to be a negative integer. But this contradicts with the Well ordering Principal which states that the least element $a$ have to be a positive integer. Hence $S$ only contains positive integer. Is my version of the proof correct. Thanks

Comment: Contradiction because least element $a$ cannot be be positive and negative at the same time.